# I can't open the profile of the author of a comment

Tags: support, profile-page, comment-links

gnat made a comment on this question:
[How does a collision engine work?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26501/how-does-a-collision-engine-work#comment43463_26501)

I tried to click on it to open his profile on the mobile app. It just expanded the comment to give comment options. I tried with my pinky and everything.

I then opened the site in desktop view (on my mobile app). I still can't click it. Instead, it just highlights the date while my finger is down.

I tried making a one line comment and opening my own profile, and it worked fine. I am guessing this has something to do with the shortness of his name combined with the single line comment.

Not a major bug to be sure, but figured it couldn't hurt to point it out.

Comment: Has he deleted his account there? Hmm . . .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not a bug. The username after a comment (or a post) is not linked to a profile when *there is no profile to link to*.

Often this happens when the author of the comment deletes their profile. Another situation (which is what happened here) is that a post gets migrated after the comment is made, and the commenter does not have an account on the destination site.

You may notice that the comment is dated by March 24, 2012 while the question was asked on March 30, 2012... This is odd, and suggests looking at the [revision history](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/posts/26501/revisions), which reveals the chain of events:

1. Question posted on Programmers; some users, including gnat, commented there.
2. Question also posted on Game Development
3. The Programmers version is migrated to Game Development, and merged into the copy that already existed there.

gnat has an account on Programmers, but not on Game Development.

So... by design.

Comment: Further note: while post usernames will get relinked if the user later creates a profile on that site, *comment* usernames won't, so even if gnat joins Game Dev, that comment will not be linked at all.